# Change File Extension Using C#

Tags: c#

I have many file types: pdf, tiff, jpeg, bmp. etc.
My question is how can I change file extension?
I tried this:

```
my file= c:/my documents/my images/cars/a.jpg;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(myffile);
myfile.replace(extension,".Jpeg");
```

No matter what type of file it is, the format I specify must be with the file name. But it does not work. I get file path from browser like `c:\..\..\a.jpg`, and the file format is `a.jpeg`. So, when I try to delete it, it gives me an error: `Cannot find the file on specified path'`. So, I am thinking it has something to do with the file extension that does not match. So, I am trying to convert `.jpg` to `.jpeg` and delete the file then.

Comment: How does it not work, (apart from being far from compiling)?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

There is: [`Path.ChangeExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx) method. E.g.:

```
var result = Path.ChangeExtension(myffile, ".jpg");
```

In the case if you also want to physically change the extension, you could use [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) method:

```
File.Move(myffile, Path.ChangeExtension(myffile, ".jpg"));
```

Comment: so will it change the extension to jpg? of original file?

Comment: @Alex I am not moving a file, i get file path from broswer like c:\..\..\a.jpg, and the file format on physical path is a.Jpeg, so when i try to delete it, it gives me error cannot find the file on specified path. so i am thinking it has some to do with the file extension is not matching. so i am trying to convert jpg to Jpeg and delete the file then.

Comment: @safi: I doubt that changing file extension to e.g. uppercase will locate a file on the disk. Are you sure the file `c:\..\..\a.jpg` (in your example) is really exists? If yes, maybe you don't have enough priviledges to delete this file? And finally, if you just want to replace file extension use `var newFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(myffile, ".Jpg");`; the `newFilePath` will contain a new file name with changed extension, physically, the file name (on disk) won't be changed.

Comment: @Alex, I tried and it didnt worked for me, so can we do like this.. c:/my documents/my images/cars/a where a is a.jpg? mean to say removing extension....not from just file name including the whole path.

Comment: @safi: see, this `var newPath = Path.ChangeExtension("c:/my documents/my images/cars/a where a is a.jpg", string.Empty)` will remove the extension from the path defined as the first method parameter; the `newPath` string variable will contain `c:/my documents/my images/cars/a where a is a.` value after this operation.

Comment: There are so many things we do create code for, but already exists in the .NET fx. `File.Move` & `Path.ChangeExtension`. Cool ! :-)

Comment: Coming from google, this is exactly what I needed. But now that I see the context, did anyone actually figure out what OP was attempting?

Answer (score 24):

You should do a move of the file to rename it. In your example code you are only changing the string, not the file:

```
myfile= "c:/my documents/my images/cars/a.jpg";
string extension = Path.GetExtension(myffile); 
myfile.replace(extension,".Jpeg");
```

you are only changing myfile (which is a string). To move the actual file, you should do

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(myfile);
f.MoveTo(Path.ChangeExtension(myfile, ".Jpeg"));
```

See [FileInfo.MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto.aspx)

Comment: I am not moving a file, i get file path from broswer like c:\..\..\a.jpg, and the file format on physical path is a.Jpeg, so when i try to delete it, it gives me error cannot find the file on specified path. so i am thinking it has some to do with the file extension is not matching. so i am trying to convert jpg to Jpeg and delete the file then

Comment: The first code does not do any replacing. You need to do `myfile=myfile.Replace(extension,".Jpeg");`

Comment: CAUTION: the extension may also be part of the filename! As in "my.pdf-file.pdf".

Answer (score 12):

try this.

```
filename = Path.ChangeExtension(".blah")
```

in you Case:

```
myfile= c:/my documents/my images/cars/a.jpg;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(myffile);
filename = Path.ChangeExtension(myfile,".blah")
```

You should look this post too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The method `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`, as the name implies, does not return the extension on the file.  In your case, it would only return "a".  You want to append your ".Jpeg" to that result.  However, at a different level, this seems strange, as image files have different metadata and cannot be converted so easily.

Answer (score 1):

### ***Convert file format to png***

```
string newfilename , 
 string filename = "~/Photo/"  + lbl_ImgPath.Text.ToString();/*get filename from specific path where we store image*/
 string newfilename = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, ".png");/*Convert file format from jpg to png*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to using `Path.ChangeExtension`

```cs
string ChangeFileExtension(ReadOnlySpan<char> path, ReadOnlySpan<char> extension)
{
    var lastPeriod = path.LastIndexOf('.');
    return string.Concat(path[..lastPeriod], extension);
}

string myfile= @"C:/my documents/my images/cars/a.jpg";
string changedFileExtesion = ChangeFileExtension(myfile, ".jpeg");

Console.WriteLine(changedFileExtesion);
// output: C:/my documents/my images/cars/a.jpeg
```