# How do I de-capitalize all file extensions given a directory?

Tags: c#, rename, tolower

```
    originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath).Where(file => !file.EndsWith(".db")).ToArray();

foreach (string file in originalFiles)
    {
         File.Move(file, file.Replace(".JPG", ".jpg"));
         File.Move(file, file.Replace(".TIFF", ".tiff"));
         File.Move(file, file.Replace(".JPEG", ".jpeg"));
         File.Move(file, file.Replace(".BMP", ".bmp"));
         File.Move(file, file.Replace(".GIF", ".gif"));
    }
```

I thought running the above would change the file extensions to lower case.

I have files in the directory:

AAA_1.jpg
AAA_2.JPG
BBB_1.TIFF
BBB_2.GIF

I want it to to be:

AAA_1.jpg
AAA_2.jpg
BBB_1.tiff
BBB_2.gif

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Here is a similar question: [Change File Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259961/change-) That should take care of your problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`ToLower()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower.aspx) method of the `String` class, and the [`ChangeExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx) method of the `Path` class.  This should allow you to lowercase all of the extensions without having to enumerate every possible extension.

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo("c:\whatever");
FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");


foreach (var file in files)
{
    File.Move(file.FullName, Path.ChangeExtension(file, 
       Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower()));     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it. Thanks for the tip Robert.

```
foreach (string file in originalFiles)
{
  File.Move(file, Path.ChangeExtension(file, Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower()));
}
```