# C# Equivalent for FILE declaration

Tags: c#, c++, file, c++builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change file extension c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259961/change-file-extension-c-sharp)

the following code is in c++, how would i represent this in c#?

```
FILE fp = fopen(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, ".DAT").c_str(), "w");
```

Another question related to this topic is:

The equivalent in c# for the following:

```
fputs((thisstring.CommaText + "\n").c_str(), fp);
```

Comment: I suspect it's not the file extension change he's interested in. Read the title of the post...

Comment: Do you want to write text (fprintf) or binary data ? In .NET that is separated.

Comment: If you have any questions -beyond your first-, please post it as a new question. =)

Comment: thisstring is a variable

Comment: fputs is Text based, use a StreanWriter.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(Path.ChangeExtension(Application.ExeName, "DAT"));
```

Comment: thanks Justin, just what i was looking for :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, got it working now...

another question related to the same topic is the equivalent in c# for the following:

fputs((thisstring.CommaText + "\n").c_str(), fp);

Comment: Please can raise this as a separate question for clarity?

Answer (score 4):

You can open (create) a FileStream based upon the EXE name:

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(
        Path.ChangeExtension(Application.ExeName, "dat"));
```

or maybe a TextWriter is closer to C/C++ `FILE` :

```
StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(
        Path.ChangeExtension(Application.ExeName, "dat"));
```

But please note that writing to the ProgramFiles folder is prohibited for normal users.

Comment: +1 for noting default access control.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't compiled it, but this might give you an idea.

```
string appName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
FileStream s = File.Open(Path.ChangeExtension(appName , ".DAT"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, got it working now... used the code Justin posted.

another question related to the same topic is the equivalent in c# for the following:

fputs((thisstring.CommaText + "\n").c_str(), fp);

Thanks Camren

Comment: var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\filepath\file.txt");
writer.Write("This is a string without line break.");
writer.WriteLine("This is a single line in the file.");