# How I can save a .xlw format on excel with c#

Tags: c#, excel, save

Well I have a little problem.

I want to save a excel file in C# which format is xlw, but I can`t.

Then I have a idea. I try to save this file in xlsx and after change the format to .xlw, but I don't know how I do this.

Anybody can help me please ?

Thanks!

---

I try this :

objExcelworkbook.SaveAs("abc.xlw",....);

or

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("abc.xlw",....);

And the file don't save with this name "abc.xlw".

So, I explain my problem:

I have a mini program that copy different excel files, but the file extension .xlw doesn't copy right. In the other hand, the file extension .xls, save right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259961/change-file-extension-using-c-sharp check this for file extension change

Comment: Any code to show us your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
objExcelworkbook.SaveAs("abc.xlw",....);
```

or

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("abc.xlw",....);
```