# Create TypeScript Declaration File from RESX file

Tags: c#, typescript, resx

I am wondering if there is a method to take a RESX file, and feed it into a TS file/some other script, that outputs a new TypeScript declaration file. This could run perhaps at build time.

Right now I don't think there are any built-in typescript methods to iterate through a ResX file, so I think this would need to be done using [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file).

It looks like I can iterate through a ResX file with a for loop as shown above, then create a new txt file and write the output in there, then [change the file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259961/change-file-extension-using-c-sharp) from txt to `.d.ts`.

Curious on thoughts of this approach or if I should try something else besides native C# (maybe T4 text templating, or some bash scripting?).

---

The final output would be something like
`output.d.ts`

```
export interface MyResXStrings extends SomeTypeScript Interface { 
    WelcomeTitle: string;  
    WelcomeSubtitle: string; 
}
```

which was created from `MyResxStrings.resx`, which has `WelcomeTitle`, and `WelcomeSubtitle`.